# Get value from push key generated

Tags: javascript, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I want to get points of respectived logged in user to be displayed from database corresponding to its push key i tried many ways but i just couldn't make it possible here is my code

```
const autoid=firebase.database().ref("user").push().key;
firebase.database().ref("/").child(autoid).set({
    email :email,
    password : password, 
    points :"500", 
    Id:autoid 
})
```

And below is my firebase realtime database picture:

[image: Realtime database]

The following code inserts the email, password, points and ID on realtime database with different key for every user that registers and i want to show the user when he is logged in to see his email and points? I tried trying different methods but I was unsuccessful anyway to do that?

```
firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((credential) => {
    firebase.database().ref("/users/" + credential.user.uid).set({
      email: credential.user.email,
      uid: credential.user.uid
    });
    alert("signed in");    
})
```

I also tried this above code to get uid as a parent file rather then getting a random push id, but I have failed to do so and I don't know where the error is the rules used for my database is:-

```
{
  "rules":{
    ".read": true, 
    ".write":true
  } 
}
```

Do I need to change the rule?

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: You could use `uid` that we could get from user object to create those documents.

Comment: Those are push key ids I can't find a way to extract the points using the push key of currently logged in user

Comment: You need to add SingleValueEvent Listener Referenced to a uid. From there you extract the whole user and use the method getPoints() that is in your user class.       https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&source=web&rct=j&url=https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/android/read-and-write&ved=2ahUKEwiojPaoh8T2AhW_h_0HHWuHAewQFnoECA0QAQ&usg=AOvVaw2WDmuUsyGannfSDbRR18Wm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To **write** the data in a node for the currently signed in user, you'd do:

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).set({
  email: email,
  password : password, 
  points: "500"
});
```

To subsequently **read** the data for the currently signed in user, you'd do:

```
const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).once("value").then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.val());
});
```

Comment: I can't get where to write data I tried to write it down on signup function (when users creates a account but it isn't being stored on database)

Comment: function signup(){
    var email = document.getElementById("email1").value;
var password = document.getElementById("password1").value;




   

    
    firebase.auth().createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
        .then((userCredential) => {
            
            
          const uid = firebase.auth().currentUser.uid;
firebase.database().ref("users").child(uid).set({
  email: email,
  password : password, 
  points: "500"
});



 
    alert("signed in");

        })